# Is there a Logstash in AWS Elasticseach service? I do not know how to access and set it

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I am Newbie who is studying ELK stack this time.

Recently, I succeeded in loading logs onto an Elasticsearch through a logback on a spring boot project. But this is like sending a log from logback to Elasticsearch _bulk uri, which exists in Elasticsearch service.

But there is still something you don't know.
How do I approach and configure logstash in aws elaticearch serivce.

I don't know where logstash is located in AWS Elasticsearch Service. Is it true that logstash exists?

So I asked a question to my friend or developer group, *but I didn't get the results I wanted.*

My friend's developer has already commented that logstash exists in the AWS Elasticsearch service, "Why are you trying to create in the wrong place, such as a separate EC2?"

Before asking questions and questions, Elasticsearch experts advised people to visit the official website to watch the video clips.

Some might call me stupid, but I tried various things to find out and find out.

I learned all the starting videos about ELK Stack on the official website of Elastic Search.

I looked for any Logstash information in the AWS Elasticsearch service reference, but all I found was the logstash-output-amazon-es plug-in in the topics below.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ko_kr/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-kibana.html

I try to figure it out, and I'm just panicking, having little sleep a few week.

And finally, I'm going to ask you, I'm thinking in two ways.

- If Logstash does not exist in AWS Elasticsearch service,
  First, deploy the spring boot application to my EC2 instance
  Second, I will need to install Logstash on this EC2 instance to configure the pipeline through logstash.conf to load logs into elasticsearch in my AWS Elasticsearch service.
- If Logstash exists in the AWS Elasticsearch service, I wonder how it approaches logstash.conf. Because I want to set the input, filter,output as I want.

please help me.

Comment: It includes the E and the K of ELK but not the L. See https://aws.amazon.com/answers/logging/centralized-logging-technical-brief/ for more on logging in AWS. It's common to collect logs using CloudWatch Logs agent and store logs in the CloudWatch Logs service. Or you could run your own installation of Logstash, of course.

Comment: @jarmod It's been a long time, but thank you for giving me a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to run Logstash on your own infrastructure. The question here is more: Do you really need Logstash? Change your Logback appender to write out JSON logs and then use Filebeat to store the data directly in Elasticsearch; no Logstash needed.

Comment: Thank you, but my purpose was to study ELK stack and install and set it up myself. In fact, when applying to a project, it would be desirable to consider filebeat as recommended.